# OwinHost.exe not working for class library project

Tags: owin, katana

I've created a new class library project with the following startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Run(ctx =>
        {
            ctx.Response.StatusCode = 200;
            ctx.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            return ctx.Response.WriteAsync("Hello from Owin");
        });
    }
}
```

I have the following packages installed:

```
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="OwinHost" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

When I attempt to run `owinhost.exe` from `/bin/debug` I get the following error:

```
Error:  System.EntryPointNotFoundException
  The following errors occurred while attempting to load the app.
 - No assembly found containing an OwinStartupAttribute.
 - No assembly found containing a Startup or [AssemblyName].Startup class.
```

Do I need to do anything else to get OwinHost.exe to work with a class library project (I had the same issue with a Console application).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you execute the OwinHost.exe without parameters, the method name needs to be `Configuration`, not `Configure`.

Also, execute `owinhost.exe` under the root path (A.K.A {projectDir}) and output the builds to /bin, not /bin/debug. Of course, these are configurable through switches to `OwinHost.exe` but this is what it needs if you wanna run it w/o any switches.

More in depth explanation is available here: [OWIN Startup Class Detection](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection) and here: [Good Old F5 Experience With OwinHost.exe on Visual Studio 2013](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/good-old-f5-experience-with-owinhost-exe-on-visual-studio-2013)

Comment: This was a typo on my behalf. Even after renaming to `Configuration` I get the same error.

Comment: The thing that was tripping me up was that I was building to /bin/debug. I attempted to use the `-d` switch to specify my build directory but [looking at the source](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/OwinHost/Program.cs) this doesn't appear to do anything.